# Using Latex beamer and natbib packages at the same time

Tags: latex, beamer

When I use both \documentclass{beamer} and \usepackage{natbib} I get the following error when running latex

```
! LaTeX Error: \newblock undefined.
```

How can I solve this? If beamer and natbib are incompatible, is there any other beamer compatible package that provides the (author, year) citing style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven’t really worked with the natbib package but I’d like to point you to the great [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package which offers a wide range of styles and it is — relatively — easy to configure your own style rules.

Well, the biblatex package seems also to have a natbib compatibility option, that defines some more natbib-like commands. Maybe you should start with

`\usepackage[natbib=true, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}`

and change the bibstyle and citestyle according to the documentation. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to change just, define newblock

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em} % important line
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \tiny{
  \bibliography{FEMbiblio}}
\end{frame}
```

One thing may not work if you want author year